Question about Laravel and Routes - Route::get vs Route::resource
I just began learning about Laravel over the past week or so, and I came across this crash course video on YouTube which spends an hour creating a simple note application with Laravel. I chose it since it was fairly new and was trying to learn Laravel 11.
Link to YouTube Video
He went on to explain all the different route configurations for NoteController within Laravel and had us type them all out.
Route::get('/note', [NoteController::class, 'index'])->name('note.index');
Route::get('/note/create', [NoteController::class, 'create'])->name('note.create');
Route::post('/note', [NoteController::class, 'store'])->name('note.store');
Route::get('/note/{id}', [NoteController::class, 'show'])->name('note.show');
Route::get('/note/{id}/edit', [NoteController::class, 'edit'])->name('note.edit');
Route::put('/note/{id}', [NoteController::class,'update'])->name('note.update');
Route::delete('/note/{id}', [NoteController::class,'destroy'])->name('note.destroy');

He then explained that we could utilize the single Route::resource command to do all of the above without typing it all out, which is nice.
Route::resource('note', NoteController::class);
The application then worked as expected without issue. I went on to create my own project utilizing the knowledge I gained through the video and decided instead of using Route::resource I would just type them all out manually to have a little more control over the application and it's routes. For some reason, whenever I created the Route::get('support/{id}'... or even the post route, I was having issues. I was scratching my head for well over a day about what was causing the issue.
I focused on the show method within the controller, and noticed it should just drop the contents of the object in the browser if there is an object with a given id, but it wasn't doing that. The browser was just showing the following:

So I decided to do a dd command, since he explained it in the video and I figured it could be helpful, and something stood out to me there:
App\Models\SupportTickets {#1315 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\SupportTicketsController.php:50
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

I noticed instantly that the connection field and table field was null. That told me that Laravel didn't know where the data was to pull it which was why it was pulling no data for a given id. This is where I was stuck for quite awhile, so I decided to pull up the original project I made from the tutorial, and try the same thing, and it actually showed data there with the same command:
App\Models\Note {#1276 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\NoteController.php:39
  #connection: "sqlite"
  #table: "notes"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

This left me very puzzled because everything looked identical between the two projects however one was behaving different over the other one. After some tinkering I realized if I stopped using Route::resource over on the Note project and just used the Route::get commend directly, it nulled out the connection and table values when performing a dd.
So that answered my question, when running php artisan make:controller NoteController --resource --model=Note that resource command essentially made it so only the resource route worked correctly.
I'd much rather do it manually to have control, but I am not sure how to create a controller that would allow me to do that. I have created a controller without the resource flag and it doesn't work with either types of routes. Is there a best practice on creating controllers within Laravel or is the resource method preferred?
Is there a way I can create a controller in such a way where I can use Route::get('/support/{id}', [SupportTicketsController::class, 'show'])->name('support.show'); instead of utilizing the resource command, that will pass the connection and table information along?

You also need to edit your post, to have a very brief couple of paragraphs of explaining the problem, and keep the detailed approach as well, but show us the problem briefly.

You should also show us a sample of your controller content.

I do have the right connection details in the .env file, because it seeds correctly and I can use the query() method to get data from it no problem. I think I did a decent job at explaining where I am in this, if I had issues connecting Laravel with the database entirely I would have stated that. It's just the routes that are not route::resource that are the problem. I can run php artisan migrate:refresh --seed no problem.

Check my answer, I have explained what the problem is with what I know so far. If it is not it, feel free to update your question with the content of Controller and/or the routes file.

Your question does not have full details (Controller content, web.php content) but it seems that in your Controller you might have something like:

**Controller**
...
public function show(App\Models\SupportTickets $supportTicket){
return [supportTicket]
...
}
**routes/web.php**
...
Route::get('/support/{id}', [SupportTicketsController::class, 'show']);
...


The issue here is that you have {id} as the parameter name in your route configuration, but the controller expects {supportTicket} since that is the name in all your controller methods. So in short, both should match, either change the controller to use the id as a parameter and use the model to Find that ID i.e: SupportTicket::find($id); or rename the route parameter in routes/web.php to be {supportTicket} (to match the parameter name in the controller).
Fixed version A

**Controller**
...
public function show(App\Models\SupportTickets $supportTicket){
return [$supportTicket];
...
}
**routes/web.php**
...
Route::get('/support/{supportTicket}', [SupportTicketsController::class, 'show']); // 
...


Fixed version B

**Controller**
...
public function show($id){
return [SupportTickets::find($id)]
...
}
**routes/web.php**
...
Route::get('/support/{id}', [SupportTicketsController::class, 'show']);
...


A small tip from what I noticed:
Your model should always be in singular format (SupportTicket)
